# Which cables are "active" in the UTP cable

Tags: cable, utp

I believe there are 4 cables inside the UTP cable that are "active" for data, the rest might be for activity and other stuff. I need to know which colors represent the data transfer from an UTP ?

Or am I wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

http://www.washington.edu/lst/help/computing_fundamentals/networking/schemes

Comment: Perfect! What I wanted.

Comment: @Elbow: Beware though that this site only covers network speeds up to 100MBit/s. For Gigabit Ethernet and upwards, all eight wires are used.

Comment: Good point @SvenW

Comment: It should also be noted that in gigE, the pairs don't actually matter that much. The devices that are built to spec *should* autonegotiate the pinout of each end. We just try to keep it following EIA/TIA 568 standards.

Comment: True enough but a good sys admin/it guy should really really enforce proper cabling practices. Some manufacturers don't have Auto MDI on by default and that leads to headaches. Personally i always cross then connecting Like devices and use straight through for unlike.

Answer (score 0):

This site hopefully will provide you with what you need! I belive for standard ethernet cable its pairs 1/2, 3/6, 4/5 and 7/8

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/layer_1/cables/tech_lan.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's not black and white. For 10/100 its pairs 1/2 (transmit), and 3/6 (receive) - unless you're using equipment that can autonegotiate. For gigabit, all pairs are used. The above links are all also correct. I'm not sure about 10GigE.